# cannot access second router in different subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, wireless-router

please help, i am new at networking with basic understanding in routing table...
i have 2 router, main router/router A and second router/ router B.

I want to access my router B from router A, router A is at ETH 2/192.168.1.1 and router B connected through router A ETH3/192.168.2.1 to router B WAN port.
The router b have WAN of 192.168.2.2 and LAN of 192.168.20.1

so to connect them, i made a static routing in router A with destination = 192.168.20.0/24 and gateway 192.168.2.2

in router B i made static routing with destination = 192.168.1.0/24 and gateway 192.168.2.1.

i thought that it would work but apparently not, currently i able to access router A devices(printer,CCTV,and other) through router B, but i cant access anything on router B through router A...

both router also have their own dhcp server

soo how do i connect them properly?

Comment: Short answer, you cannot. A router creates a private network. You basically have a network inside a network. They cannot communicate with each other, other than through routing itself. Can you explain why you placed your routers in series?

Comment: If you wish to connect them put them on the same subnet. I do both ways - your way to isolate and same subnet to connect.

Comment: @LPChip: But OP did specify that they've configured routes from one network to another, i.e. literally what one needs to have networks communicate with each other. (Didn't mention anything about firewall though...)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest was would be to eliminate the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet. Put the WAN port of router B on a static IP on 192.168.1.0/24, pick an address outside router A's DHCP pool. This way, router B's WAN IP is on router A's subnet.

I suspect your issue is that router A cannot access the IP you have assigned for routing because it is in a different subnet.

The configuration you have described might work if you were connecting the routers WAN port to WAN port, but I would expect your internet connection is on router A's WAN port, so you need a different configuration.

For more information, the output of your routing tables and the errors you receive if you try to ping a host on one subnet from the other will tell a lot more about where the route is failing. Most likely, you will see an error from one of the routers or your computer saying it has no route to the gateway IP.